Questions about Nietzsche's "On Truth and Lies in a Nonmoral Sense" - Against language? Anti-philosophy?
Introduction
A few weeks ago, we had a lecture on the Philosophy of Culture for which we had to read this essay called “On Truth and Lies in a Nonmoral Sense” and I got a few questions. I thought they would not be suitable for the lecture due to time constraints, and our professor does not like to answer philosophical questions by email. We had an internal discussion forum where I posted these questions, but it did not get any momentum. In the light of this, would you be able to help me?
First Question(s) – On Language
Why does Nietzsche feel the necessity to establish initially that humans "dislike the harmful consequences of lies" rather than simply stating that they "dislike lies" in order to effectively critique language?
Would Nietzsche still be capable of undermining language if humans were to embrace truth for its intrinsic value rather than for its consequences?
I understand that this sort of peace agreement splits truths and lies into good and bad things due to their nature or consequences, and thus Nietzsche picks up from that point. But I still don’t understand why exactly a lie is not bad in itself, rather than due to its consequences, even more so given the entire account that Nietzsche gives of language.
In fact, if a certain language is merely a metaphor for what really is out there in the sphere of reality, then not only lies but also anything that you express with language may be harmful, including truths. If I can rephrase my question: if language is nothing but “metaphors, metonyms and anthropomorphisms”, then why is it not harmful in itself?
It seems to me that even if you keep yourself within the “rules of the game” (see Huizinga) of this peace agreement, i.e., if you don’t lie, insofar as you are using language to describe the world, then you may cause harm regardless.
Second Question(s) – On Anti-philosophy
I'm also a bit confused regarding the ultimate objective or message of this essay. Was it composed to critique language as a mere instrument? Is it an argument against objective truth/reality? Or does it go even deeper by critiquing the pursuit of knowledge itself? If, according to Nietzsche, the universe started without knowledge and will ultimately end without it, is he attempting to demolish the entire framework of philosophy, science, and religion (Christianity in particular) or is he merely highlighting how humanity's pursuit of an illusory truth leads to decadence?
After the lecture it seems perhaps a bit clearer now that Nietzsche was critiquing the European culture as a whole, its value system and highlighting its decadence.
But I still think there is something a bit unanswered there, namely about the knowledge framework of philosophy. It sort of ties together with this question from the lecture: “How is it possible that in European culture people have come to regard themselves as desiring truth for its own sake?”
It sounds almost anti-philosophical, in the sense that with philosophy you try to get to the truth, right? Lovers of wisdom and all that. Philosophers are mostly concerned with truth and declare it to be the most valuable thing in itself. But then if, according to Nietzsche, these illusions are necessary to our survival, because they keep us safe, and stable, and make us understand what surrounds us, then why should philosophers or human beings in general even strive for it?
Where does this 'will to truth' come from, if truth as an illusion that we forgot to be an illusion is not something you should want to unmask, precisely because all these dissimulations and metaphors satisfy the human drive/desire for deception, i.e., the intellect manifests itself in humans when it “unfolds its principle powers in dissimulation”. Then if human beings use the intellect/dissimulation as an act of survival, then why should we strive for truth? Wouldn’t that mean that human beings would perish?
In other words, as a summary, the question turns out to be: how do we go from here if truth is not something to strive for? How does philosophy manage to defend itself from Nietzsche's attack on its foundations/essence?

You'll get a better response if you split your two questions into two questions


Nietzsche point on lie is that there is no ontological difference between it and truth. That leads us to the idea that there is no evil nor good in them, they are kind of the same thing. It's a question of pragmaticism for him, if a lie or truth helps us, then they are good but not in metaphysical sense but in practical one.
Nietzche's criticism on philosophy is an attack on metaphysics. Metaphysics leads us to nihilism which can be defined as anti-life tendencies (metaphysics as detachment from "real" life). But there is also a paradox here, his philosophy of life is really a metaphysical doctrine.


Question(s) 1:
In this essay, Nietzsche starts from the perspective that inherent nature of humans is to dissimulate (i.e.,to lie):

As a means for the preserving of the individual, the intellect unfolds
its principal powers in dissimulation, which is the means by which
weaker, less robust individuals preserve themselves – since they have
been denied the chance to wage the battle for existence with horns or
with the sharp teeth of beasts of prey. This art of dissimulation
reaches its peak in man. Deception, flattering, lying, deluding,
talking behind the back, putting up a false front, living in borrowed
splendor, wearing a mask, hiding behind convention, playing a role for
others and for oneself – in short, a continuous fluttering around the
solitary flame of vanity – is so much the rule and the law among men
that there is almost nothing which is less comprehensible than how an
honest and pure drive for truth could have arisen among them.

Lying is neither good nor bad; it's normative or even definitional for humanity. Lying only becomes an issue because men want/need to be (in Nietzsche's terms) 'part of the herd': members of social groups. Being part of a herd means that certain dissimulations are codified as 'true' to keep people from fighting over them. For a dumbish example, consider marriage. From Nietzsche's perspective marriage would be a complete dissimulation — an illusory bond artificially sanctified by someone who pretends to have spiritual authority — but we all codify marriage as 'truth' mainly to avoid men and women rutting in the street like big-horned sheep to claim spouses. And the worry is that if one violates these codified dissimulations in ways that harm others, then one might be ostracized or excluded from the herd:

If he [misuses fixed conventions] in a selfish and moreover harmful
manner, society will cease to trust him and will thereby exclude him.
What men avoid by excluding the liar is not so much being defrauded as
it is being harmed by means of fraud. Thus, even at this stage, what
they hate is basically not deception itself, but rather the
unpleasant, hated consequences of certain sorts of deception.

See, we need to get away from the idea that Nietzsche is talking about anything like 'objective' lies or truths here. Language is dissimulation; human behavior is dissimulation. 'Truth' is merely those dissimulations that are conventionally or normatively acceptable, and 'lies' are those that aren't. It isn't that lies hurt people and truths don't; it's that the language which society deems harmful is codified as lies, and language it deems acceptable is codified as truth.
It's like the 'love poem' paradox. If someone writes a love poem to their sweetheart, everyone involved knows it's flowery artistic bullshit. But everyone involved likes it, and no one ever accuses a love poem of being a lie, even when it most assuredly is.
Question(s) 2:
Nietzsche, as is all too frequently for him, isn't reaching for a conclusion here. He's reaching for an understanding by presenting a dichotomy and asking us to reach beyond it. The dichotomy here is between the 'rational' and 'intuitive' types. The first is stolid, conventional, scientific: it takes all of the conventionally accepted dissimulations as unquestioned truth, builds its lifeworld within the established structures of language, and is constantly refining, reconstructing, shoring up, and expanding those frameworks. Such types deceive themselves with normalcy, safe and secure in the blind acceptance of the fabrications as truths, and never lie in the sense of breaking a dissimulation that others rely on. The intuitive type, by contrast, is creative and artistic: it tears down the conventionally accepted dissimulations it finds unappealing and builds new, more beautiful, fanciful, or elegant ones; this type lies (in the conventional sense of breaking dissimulations), but only in ways that entrance or elevate or entertain or mystify. The intuitive type builds a web of dissimulations that are beautiful (or at times horrible); the rational type builds a web of dissimulations that are stable, secure, and productive.
I think Nietzsche wants to paint this particular image of the world in which there are different ways of relating to the dissimulating nature of humanity, without really approving or disapproving of either. It's about seeing how even our most secure and comforting thoughts — the precepts of science, the dictates of religion, the heights of reason and imagination — are themselves merely useful and pleasurable pretenses.
